# Slow web requests in java when using Ant

Tags: java, ant

I'm working on a school project that uses `Apache Ant`. In my project I am performing web requests.

Check out a specific target in my `build.xml` file:

```
<target name="daemon" depends="build.all">
    <java 
        classpathref="run.path.id"
        classname="xxx.xxx.Daemon"
        fork="false">
    </java>
</target>
```

If I run this target, all web requests take approximately 30 seconds (**each**) to complete. If I change the `fork` attribute to:

```
<target name="daemon" depends="build.all">
    <java 
        classpathref="run.path.id"
        classname="xxx.xxx.Daemon"
        fork="true">
    </java>
</target>
```

the requests complete almost immediately (less than a second).

---

From https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html about the `fork` attribute:

> if enabled triggers the class execution in another VM (disabled by default)

Why does this have such a tremendous impact on the performance of web requests?

---

#### UPDATE:

This is only an issue on Windows. I tested 2 separate machines running Windows. Both exhibited this behavior. I then spun up one VM (running Ubuntu) on each and the daemon target ran perfectly regardless of the value of the `fork` attribute.

Comment: Did you try to debug this issue? Provide JVM remote debug options to your ant startup and connect IDE to running daemon (when fork=false).

Comment: Tried the combination `fork=true clonevm=true` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you run a `java` command this will create a process of it's own which will run in a separate thread within the same JVM. So while the process is created from the thread that runs `Ant`, it does not run immeadiatly.

Comment: This is not only a startup problem. The daemon runs indefinitely or until a user specifically requests it to shut down. Throughout its lifetime, a user can issue a web request (at any time) and it will still take 30 seconds to complete.